# Is it possible to release flutter app from Android Studio for IOS in windows?

Tags: flutter

I have just created simple app. I am done building apk file for andriod. But i want to get app for ios, but i don't have Mac. Is there a way to get ios without Mac?

Comment: No... it is not. You have to have mac to do it

Comment: Can we create VM as a MAC on windows?

Comment: No.. you need to have mac.. no VM. As far as I know that is apple policy

Comment: Ok thank you very much for answer.